# zone.js: how to import zone.js library into node script

Tags: zone.js

I am trying to set up a small node script to play with `zone.js`. But I am confused about how to require this library into node script.

My script goes as following:

```
var Zone = require('zone.js/dist/zone-node.js');

console.log('test...', Zone)

function main() {
    foo();
    setTimeout(doSomething, 2000);
    bar();
    baz();
}

function doSomething() {
    console.log('Async task');
}  

function foo() {
    console.log('foo')
}
function bar() {
    console.log('bar')
}
function baz() {
    console.log('baz')
}

// Zone.run(main)
```

The imported Zone is an empty object. And what's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example repo.
https://github.com/JiaLiPassion/zone-node
the `Zone` is not an exported object, it is registered to `global`.